# Batch connecting with sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to make a batch script which checks all customers automatically
in a database if there are invalid objects.

The issue I have is that when I am trying to print out the results .txt file is not so readable as contains connection info.

Is there any way to print in a file only the invalid without any other info ?
Thanks in advance

My code is below :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

set "Server[1]=DB1"
set "Server[2]=DB2"
set "Server[3]=DB3"

set "Message="
:Menu
cls
echo.%Message%

set "x=0"
:MenuLoop
set /a "x+=1"
if defined Server[%x%] (
    call echo   %x%. %%Server[%x%]%%
    goto MenuLoop
)
echo.


:Prompt
set "Input="
set /p "Input=Select the DATABASE which will be checked : "

if not defined Input goto Prompt
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
set "Input=%Input:^=%"
set "Input=%Input:<=%"
set "Input=%Input:>=%"
set "Input=%Input:&=%"
set "Input=%Input:|=%"
set "Input=%Input:(=%"
set "Input=%Input:)=%"
:: Equals are not allowed in variable names
set "Input=%Input:^==%"
call :Validate %Input%

:: Process Input
call :Process %Input%
goto End

:Validate
set "Next=%2"
if not defined Server[%1] (
    set "Message=Invalid Input: %1"
    goto Menu
)
if defined Next shift & goto Validate
goto :eof

:Process
set "Next=%2"
call set "Server=%%Server[%1]%%"

:: Run Checks
:: Step 2. Match on the Server names and perform checks for each
if "%Server%" EQU "DB1"   echo checks for DB1 ...
if "%Server%" EQU "DB2"   echo checks for DB2 ...
if "%Server%" EQU "DB3"   echo checks for DB3 ...

set hostname=%Server%.domain.gr:1528
set password=pass

echo Report > Report.txt
echo. >> Report.txt

for %%S in (
  customer1
  customer2
  customer3
  customer4
) do ( 
    echo Customer %% checked .... [OK]
    echo Customer %%S  >> Report.txt
    exit|sqlplus  SYS/"%password%"@%hostname%/%%S  as SYSDBA @check_objects.sql >> Report.txt
    echo *****  >> Report.txt
)

set "Server[%1]="
if defined Next shift & goto Process
goto :eof

:End
endlocal
pause >nul
```

**check_objects.sql**

```
Spool check_objects.sql

select OBJECT_NAME || ' ' || OBJECT_TYPE
from dba_objects
where status = 'INVALID'
/
```

Comment: The first code blurb looks like a Windows batch file, is that correct? Could you add an example of the "connection info" that you're trying to avoid?

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Nov 24 17:58:54 2016

 

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 
Yes the first is batch file.
Connected to:

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

no rows selected
Elapsed: 00:00:00.06

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

Comment: Martin is right on. Try adding the -s argument to your sqlplus command.

Answer (score 1):

Try sqlplus -s
Also want to check:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm

Regards.